# Command button running very slow

Tags: excel, vba

My worksheet has about 30 columns and 11000 rows filled with data,
I run the following code in vbe and it takes only 1.7 sec

but assigned to a ActiveX command button and clicks it, takes more than 2 minutes and it happens the same to running the macro from the developer ribbon

Anyone could explain why? Thanks a lot!

my code

```
Sub filter()


    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    Dim c1 As Variant, c2 As Variant, c3 As Variant
    
    With ActiveSheet
    
        FirstRow = .Range("A20").End(xlDown).Row
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        Set rngData = .Range("A" & FirstRow & ":A" & LastRow)
        
        c1 = .Rows("3:3").Find(What:=xxx _
        , LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
        
        c2 = .Rows("3:3").Find(What:=xxx _
        , LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
        
        c3 = .Rows("3:3").Find(What:=xxx _
        , LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
        
        
    End With
    
    
    With rngData
    
        .AutoFilter Field:=c1, _
                        Criteria1:=xxxx
                        
        .AutoFilter Field:=c2, _
                        Criteria1:=Array(xxx), Operator:=xlFilterValues


    End With
    
    Range("A2:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select

    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic


End Sub
```

Comment: How about using Form Control CommandButton instead of ActiveX CommandButton?

Comment: Start by using `Option Explicit` and declaring all variables. Then make sure that the code runs on the same worksheet of the same workbook. If the command button is in `Sheet1` then use e.g. `Sheet1` or `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` instead of `ActiveSheet`. This calculation of `FirstRow` looks pretty suspicious. There is one occurrence of `xxxx` and a few `xxx`-s to who you don't assign a value.